# How many solutions are there to the equation $x + y + z = 8$ if each of $x$,$y$ and $z$ is either a positive whole number or zero?

Tags: combinatorics

How many solutions are there to the equation $$x + y + z = 8$$ if each of $x$, $y$ and $z$ is either a positive whole number or zero?

On a maths website it says the answer is $28$ but my mother worked out that it is $45$. I do not know which answer is correct. Please tell me which answer is correct.

Thank you

Comment: no limitation on if x,y and z need to be distinct ?  are (x,y,z),(x,z,y),(y,x,z),(y,z,x),(z,x,y),(z,y,x) all considered different ?

Comment: I'm having a hard time seeing how the answer could be 28.  But the question is ambiguous as commenter have said.

Comment: If permutations are counted as one.  (1+2+5 is the same as 5+1+2) Then there are 10. If numbers be distinct but permutations are different there are 30 ways.  If both numbers distinct and order doesn't matter there are 5.  And your mother's which I believe I correct has 45 ways.  I just don't get 28.

Comment: @fleablood  We obtain the solution $28$ if we ask how many nonnegative integer solutions the equation $x + y + z = 6$ has.

Comment: And 6 is the same thing as 8.  How silly of me not to see that ;)

Answer (score 3):

If there is no limitation on the numbers being distinct and permutations of the same numbers amongst the variables are counted separately (i.e. for instance $(1,3,4)$ and $(3,4,1)$ are distinct), then it's very easy.

First let $y + z = w$

Consider $x + w = 8$

There are nine possibilities for $x$, ranging from $8$ to $0$. $w$ is "fixed" by the choice of each $x$, giving a range from $0$ to $8$ respectively.

For each value of $w$, draw up a table of $y$ and $z$ pairs.

You will find (for example) that for $w = 3$, you can have $(y,z) = (0,3);(1,2);(2,1);(3,0)$, i.e. $4$ possibilities.

For each value of $w$ (and therefore $x$), you have $w+1$ possibilities.

So the sum is simply $1 + 2 + ... + 9 = \frac 12 (9)(10) = 45$.

That's the answer your mother got. But you should check the question carefully to see if they had further conditions (like $x,y,z$ should be distinct), because that can seriously affect the answer.

But if you've reproduced the question exactly, then $45$ is right.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Sorry I meant nine, but typed eight. Fixed. Feeling under the weather today. I've also found another error and fixed it (relating to the the value of $3$ instead of $4$ for my $w$ example).

Answer (score 1):

Your mother is correct.

A particular solution of the equation
$$x + y + z = 8$$
in the nonnegative integers corresponds to the placement of two addition signs in a row of eight ones.  For instance,
$$+ 1 1 1 1 1 + 1 1 1$$
corresponds to the solution $x = 0$, $y = 5$, and $z = 3$, while 
$$1 1 1 + 1 1 + 1 1 1$$
corresponds to the solution $x = 3$, $y = 2$, and $z = 3$.  Hence, the number of solutions of the equation $x + y + z = 8$ in the nonnegative integers is the number of ways two addition signs can be inserted in a row of eight ones, which is 
$$\binom{8 + 2}{2} = \binom{10}{2} = \frac{10!}{2!8!} = \frac{10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8!}{2 \cdot 1 \cdot 8!} = 5 \cdot 9 = 45$$ 
since we must choose which two of the ten positions (for eight ones and two addition signs) will be filled with addition signs.

More generally, the number of solutions of the equation
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \cdots + x_k = n$$
in the nonnegative integers is the number of ways we can insert $k - 1$ addition signs in a row of $n$ ones, which is
$$\binom{n + k - 1}{k - 1}$$
since we must choose which $k - 1$ of the $n + k - 1$ positions (for $n$ ones and $k - 1$ addition signs) will be filled with addition signs.

**Note:**  In particular, the equation
$$x + y + z = n$$
has 
$$\binom{n + 2}{2} = \frac{(n + 2)!}{2!n!} = \frac{(n + 2)(n + 1)n!}{2 \cdot 1 \cdot n!} = \frac{(n + 2)(n + 1)}{2}$$
solutions in the nonnegative integers.  Setting this equal to the website's answer of $28$ yields
\begin{align*}
\frac{(n + 2)(n + 1)}{2} & = 28\\
(n + 2)(n + 1) & = 56\\
n^2 + 3n + 2 & = 56\\
n^2 + 3n - 54 & = 0\\
n^2 + 9n - 6n - 54 & = 0\\
n(n + 9) - 6(n + 9) & = 0\\
(n - 6)(n + 9) & = 0
\end{align*}
Solving for $n$ yields $n = 6$ or $n = -9$.  Since the sum of nonnegative integers cannot be negative, $n = 6$.  Hence, we may conclude that the equation 
$$x + y + z = 6$$
has $28$ solutions in the nonnegative integers.